# Dynamically create typedef or change function return type

Tags: c++

I am using `dlib` library for non-linear opitmization. I have looked examples and wrote my program as in example. Everything works fine. Here is code example:

```
    const int N = 9;
    typedef matrix<double,N,1> parameter_vector;
    parameter_vector residual_derivative{
      .....
     }
```

Now, I want to be able to dynamically change number of parameters to be optimized. How should I do it? I know that it is not possible to dynamically create `typedef`. I want to do something like this(it is not compiling)

```
class A{
      public:
      OptimizationWrapper(int N):N(N){
          typedef matrix<double,N,1> parameter_vector;
      }
      int N;
      parameter_vector residual_derivative{
      .....
      }
};
```

I found only one solution. It is to make 'parameter_vector' size to be lesser then max number of optimize parameters:

```
     typedef matrix<double,100,1> parameter_vector;
     int N;  //real number of parameters
```

However this method slows program. Is there another solution?

Comment: Do you mean dynamic as in at runtime, or dynamic as in specifying at the place you're calling it?

Comment: @Dark Falcon  By dynamic I mean at runtime. After program compiled I will change number of parameters.

Comment: @lnk: You can't change types at runtime. Perhaps a dynamic array (`std::vector<double>`) is what you want to supply a runtime-specified number of parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify the size at runtime and still use the compile-time construct of using `N` to instantiate a template. If you wish to do it at compile time you can make a template function or class:

```
template<int N> matrix<double,N,1> residual_derivative(...) {...}
```

The only way to do this at runtime is to use a type which is resized at runtime. I don't know which matrix template you're using, but since it seems to be one-dimensional, perhaps you could return a `std::vector<double>` instead.

Comment: I cannot use `std::vector<double>` because function `residual_derivative` will be passed to `dlib` function `solve_least_squares_lm` and return type of `residual_derivative`  should be `matrix`; Solution with template also doesn't work, because I cannot call function `residual_derivative<N>(...)` where N is dynamically changable variable. I can call this function only this way: `residual_derivative<10>(...)`. In other word in this solution N should be known at compile time, but I don't know it.

Comment: You don't have a choice. It is either a compile-time constant or you can't do it then. You could always switch on the value and call the appropriate instantiation of `solve_least_squares_lm`. That's going to bloat your code and be a pain to maintain, but that's the only way to choose a compile-time value at runtime. Consider some template metaprogramming if you have to handle more than a few values of `N`.

Comment: I am using templates now. And code is looking like this switch(N){case 1: ... break; ...case 100:... break; So there 300 additional lines of code. Is there another solution? I have tried to use `std::map` to store `int` as key and function pointer as value. but since return type of function differ from each other it seems like it is not possible;

Comment: The return type of `solve_least_squares_lm` is `double`. Move the template higher up in your logic.

Comment: @lnk: You can make a recursive compile-time template to replace your switch with a half dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The [matrix](http://dlib.net/dlib/matrix/matrix_abstract.h.html#matrix) has constructors that let you set the size at runtime.  Call one of those to do it.  Here are a bunch of examples:

```
matrix<double> mat(4,5); 
matrix<double,0,1> column_vect(6);
```